# checking liked user in wordpress rest api

Tags: custom-field, rest-api

i want check liked user in wordpress rest api.

liked user store in custom meta field "cd_liked_disliked_users" and when return it : [image]

i use below code for checking liked user but its not work , whats wrong ?

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'base', '/like/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_test',
  ));
});

function my_test (WP_REST_Request $request){
        $user_ip    = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $id         = $request['id'];
        $all_users = (array)get_post_meta( $id, 'cd_liked_disliked_users');
        if ( isset( $all_users[ $user_ip ] ) ) {
            return $all_users[ $user_ip ];
        } else {
            return 'New User';
        }
}
```

Comment: Try 'base/v1' instead 'base' into register_rest_route( 'base', '/like/(?P<id>\d+)', I don't know much about this.

Comment: this is a bad question, where is the JS code, where is the code setting the meta, why don't you return json.... what debugging steps have you done?

Comment: it's not need JS, whats the meta code setting ? it's custom meta field
look image it,s return array but i need check array items